# Multi-threaded SSL / TLS version switching

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, wcf

We have `Wcf` service (core service) consumed by an `asp.net mvc`. This core service integrate with other third-party services to achieve some use cases. All  these third-party service endpoints are exposed via `https` but differs when it comes to the supported SSL/TLS versions (1.0,1.1,1.2).

We don’t have much control over this and simply stick a specific ( supported ) SSL/TLS version just before connecting with any given third-party service. i.e. Whenever the core service want to consume any third party service, it set the `ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol` to supported SSL/TLS version (third-party ask us to connect using version x.x or higher).

```
    // brief expression of logic which switch TLS version 1.2
    var currentSecurityProtocol = ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol; // get the current security protocol.
    try
    {

        ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback += delegate { return true; };
        ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
        //now get/post data to/from third party service
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
       //report it
    }
    finally
    {
        ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = currentSecurityProtocol;
        ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = null;
    }
```

**Question:**

1. How to re-implement the above of TLS version switching logic to work
   seamlessly on  multi-threaded environment?

I managed to write logic which synchronize access through a lock on `ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol` property. But this attempt affect the performance of other connected clients ( when they consume any other third party offering/ service)

Comment: Multithreading doesn't affect how TLS works. `ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol` is a *flag* with the TLS versions you are willing to accept. The server and client will negotiate and pick the highest version acceptable to both.

Comment: BTW you should require at least TLS11. 1.0 is not considered safe. You should consider requiring TLS12 unless the other party has a significant reason to downgrade for a short time only. Airlines, banks, Google etc already require TLS1.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could specify multiple version of Tls so that you don't need to change it during runtime. The below code means that it support `TLS1.0`, `TLS1.1` and `TLS1.2`.

If the client supports `TLS1.2` or below, `TLS1.2` is used to create a connection

If the client support `TLS1.1` or below, the highest available security protocol which is `TLS1.1` is used.

```
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls | SecurityProtocolType.Tls11 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
```

Comment: Thanks in advance for your answer. But I am not clear on how this will work in a multi-threaded scenario since ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol is a static ( app domain/gloabl in scope) variable. Can you explain further on how this approach would help me .

Comment: @Nair multithreading has nothing to do with the protocol version used. `ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol` is the minimum allowed TLS version. Both client and server *negotiate* the version starting from the highest

Comment: Let's say, I have 2 services A & B where maximum supported TLS version for A is 1.0 and B is 1.2. Now, what if my core service call service A & B in parallel where A got scheduled (executed) first and then B. In such scenario,  it is highly likely to have data race issue (the versions field is static). So the TLS version for A now possibly be 1.2 which won’t be support by the time we upload/post data to third-party server.

Comment: With the sample code, two connections will be created using both 1.0 and 1.2

Comment: @RawitasKrungkaew, Answer is accepted. I was having a wrong idea on switching and version negotiation and hence bit muddled up. Thanks.